# Why is this floating point arithmetic compiled so strangely (without optimization)?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, floating-point, g++

I compiled the following function with level 0 and 3 optimization using 
`g++` version `4.7.2 20120921`:

```
double function1(double a, double b)
{
  return (a+b)*(a+b);
}
```

Disassembly of the level 0 optimized version provides:

```
0000000000000000 <_Z9function1dd>:
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   f2 0f 11 45 f8          movsd  QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],xmm0
   9:   f2 0f 11 4d f0          movsd  QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],xmm1
   e:   f2 0f 10 45 f8          movsd  xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  13:   66 0f 28 c8             movapd xmm1,xmm0
  17:   f2 0f 58 4d f0          addsd  xmm1,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
  1c:   f2 0f 10 45 f8          movsd  xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  21:   f2 0f 58 45 f0          addsd  xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
  26:   f2 0f 59 c1             mulsd  xmm0,xmm1
  2a:   f2 0f 11 45 e8          movsd  QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],xmm0
  2f:   48 8b 45 e8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
  33:   48 89 45 e8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],rax
  37:   f2 0f 10 45 e8          movsd  xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
  3c:   5d                      pop    rbp
  3d:   c3                      ret
```

Level 3 optimization provides:

```
0000000000000000 <_Z9function1dd>:
   0:   f2 0f 58 c1             addsd  xmm0,xmm1
   4:   f2 0f 59 c0             mulsd  xmm0,xmm0
   8:   c3                      ret
```

In the unoptimized version, why does the code do so much extra work? Specifically, what causes the 4 instructions after `mulsd`? All they do is move `xmm0` to memory, from memory to `rax` then back to memory and then back to `xmm0`.

Comment: `In the unoptimized version, why does the code do so much extra work?`  Well, that's why it's called "unoptimized".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So the compiler starts with 3 and then adds code to unoptimize it to level 0? :)

Comment: More than likely, the compiler doesn't "look ahead" and sees that you are multiplying the same quantity `a+b`  (so it might as well have been `(a+b) * (c+d)`.  The lines afterwards look like a setup of the return value in the `rax` register.

Comment: If you compile 'int a = 2; int b = 2; int c = a + b' for example and compile it unoptimised, the compiler will go ahead and add those in registers. Optimised it wouldn't.

Comment: @teppic in that case it loads 4 to `c` directly in the optimized case. In the unoptimized case doesn't save it to unnecessary memory locations.

Comment: @stardt what I'm saying is that if you turn off optimisation the compiler will generate assembly as close as possible to what you've written literally, even if it's clearly possible to do it with a much quicker way.

Comment: @teppic I understand, but in this case it seems to be doing more than I requested.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie SSE class values are returned in `xmm0` (http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf). Perhaps the compiler by default saves results to `rax` and then in this case transfers it to `xmm0` as required but doesn't know it can move between `rax` and `xmm0` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible view of what the compiler thinks it is doing. 
A non-optimizing compiler takes a very local view of things. It does not look ahead to what it is going to do next. It may be using a very restricted set of operations. For example, it seems to be limiting some of its working transfers to being between stack and xmm0, or between stack and rax.

Another aspect of the one-size-fits-all approach is that if something needs doing in some cases, it tends to get done all the time. In particular, some functions need enough registers to require saving parameters and intermediate results to the stack. The optimizing compiler will only do that if necessary. The non-optimizing compiler does it unconditionally.

```
0000000000000000 <_Z9function1dd>:
// Push the stack
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
// Save the parameters to stack temporaries
   4:   f2 0f 11 45 f8          movsd  QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],xmm0
   9:   f2 0f 11 4d f0          movsd  QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],xmm1
// Load the temporary representing a into register xmm1, via xmm0
   e:   f2 0f 10 45 f8          movsd  xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  13:   66 0f 28 c8             movapd xmm1,xmm0
// Add the temporary representing b leaving (a+b) in xmm1
  17:   f2 0f 58 4d f0          addsd  xmm1,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
// Load the temporary representing a into xmm0
  1c:   f2 0f 10 45 f8          movsd  xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
// Add the temporary representing b, leaving (a+b) in xmm0
  21:   f2 0f 58 45 f0          addsd  xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
// Multiply (a+b)*(a+b)
  26:   f2 0f 59 c1             mulsd  xmm0,xmm1
// Store the multiply result in a stack temporary
  2a:   f2 0f 11 45 e8          movsd  QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],xmm0
// Load the return value into rax
  2f:   48 8b 45 e8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
// Move the return value to xmm0 via a stack temporary
  33:   48 89 45 e8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],rax
  37:   f2 0f 10 45 e8          movsd  xmm0,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
// and return
  3c:   5d                      pop    rbp
  3d:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: Can you suggest any references to confirm that this is how gcc works? I'd be interested to find out if it uses `rax` because this is a default return value destination even for data classes that do not ultimately belong there.

Comment: No, no references - I was going by general experience of how unoptimized code generation works. It would be typical to split setting up a return value into two steps: first get the value to a standard location, then move that standard location, if necessary, to a type-appropriate location.